# store every new output of function of for loop in new varible

Tags: python

I have a list of 97 images of size 1000 x 1000 and I want to crop every image into 25 smaller images and make a for loop that take the first cropped image
of every image and store it into a new variable, the second cropped image of every image and stores it into another variable and so on. So I would end up with 25 variables each containing 97 cropped images.

I have the function to crop the images but I cannot figure out how to store them into separate variables.

`crop_time_1` is the list with the 97 full-sized images

crop is the function which crops the images into 200x200 images

```py
new_df = []
for i in crop_time_1:
    f = crop(i, 200, 200)
    new_df.append(f)
```

So now I ended up with `new_df` of length 97 and the length of `new_df[0]` is 25

Comment: And what exactly is your problem here? You don't want to use a list?

Comment: is there a reason you need to store them in variables and not a data structure instead from which you can access them by index, slice, or key?

Comment: You could use the ugly solution of using `exec`, i.e. `exec(f"var_{i} = new_df[i][0]")`. Do that in a loop on `i` and in the end of the loop you will have 97 variables named `var_0`, `var_1`, and so on. But then again, why not just use the list??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not create variables in a loop, instead create an array.

Something according to following lines should do it:

```
# Create array of 25 empty arrays
parts = [[] for x in xrange(25)]
for partitioned_image in f:
    for index, part in enumerate(partitioned_image):
        parts[index].append(part)
```

Now to access nth cropped parts image or in sense one of the variables you described: `parts[n]`